# Get data from 2 different forms and continue the same table row

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me get this done since it's driving me crazy already.

I'm new to this whole process so what seems easy for you might be a nightmare for me, and no, google didn't help :(

So, i'm having one mysql table named member with the following structure:

> - mem_id
> - username
> - password
> - firstname
> - lastname
> - titlu (title)
> - descriere (description)
> - joy (integer)
> - comm

I'm parsing user details using execute.php looking like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db.php');
$username=$_POST['username'];

$result  =  mysqli_query($db,"SELECT  *  FROM  member  WHERE  username='$username'");
$num_rows  =  mysqli_num_rows($result);

if  ($num_rows)  {
header("location:  index.php?remarks=failed");
}
else
{
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
mysqli_query($db,"INSERT  INTO  member(firstname,  lastname,  username,  password)VALUES('$firstname',  '$lastname',  '$username',  '$password')");
header("location:  index.php?remarks=success");
}
?>
```

Now i have another form that inserts gift details and must continue filling the same row in mysql.

I've tried the following but no luck:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db.php');
$username=$_POST['username'];

$result  =  mysqli_query($db,"SELECT  *  FROM  member  WHERE  username='$username'");
$num_rows  =  mysqli_num_rows($result);

if  ($num_rows)  {
header("location:  index.php?remarks=failed");
}
else
{
$titlu = $_POST['titlu'];
$descriere = $_POST['descriere'];
$joy = $_POST['joy'];
$comm = $_POST['comm'];
$sql = "UPDATE member 
            SET titlu = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[titlu])."'
            SET descriere = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[descriere])."'
            SET joy = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[joy])."'
            SET comm = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[comm])."'
            WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'";
header("location:  welcome.php?remarks=success");
}
?>
```

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: In your second file you're doing query for select the user, count the rows. If there is more than one row, you redirect to remarks=failed. So you can't update the data, because if the username exists it will redirect false and if it don't exists it can't make an update since the user doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me clear it out please?

Comment: Also you are doing `$sql = ...` which will not be triggered, use `mysqli_query($sql);`

Comment: Just turn your if condition. The code in the "else" part should be in the "if" part. Thats all. And as debute said, mysqli_query($sql) instead of just $sql =  havent seen this one.

Comment: You shouldn't mix `mysqli_` with `mysql_`. In particular, `mysql_real_escape_string` should've been `mysqli_real_escape_string`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to learn more on how to prevent it.

Comment: @pang thank you very much for that but that's not in my project scope. I just need the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Change your second file to the below code. it will redirect to `index.php?remark=failed` only if no user exist with the given username

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include('db.php');
    $username=$_POST['username'];

    $result  =  mysqli_query($db,"SELECT  *  FROM  member  WHERE  username='$username'");
    $num_rows  =  mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if  (!$num_rows)  {
    header("location:  index.php?remarks=failed");
    }
    else
    {
    $titlu = $_POST['titlu'];
    $descriere = $_POST['descriere'];
    $joy = $_POST['joy'];
    $comm = $_POST['comm'];
    $sql = "UPDATE member 
                SET titlu = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[titlu])."',
                descriere = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[descriere])."',
               joy = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[joy])."',
                comm = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[comm])."'
                WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'";
mysqli_query($sql);
    header("location:  welcome.php?remarks=success");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't resolve my problem, data is still not added in the missing table columns. 

I'm trying a different approach now. I'll update soon

Comment: @MureaAdrian I think in the second file $_POST[username] is null. That will be the roblem

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it done by using:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('db.php');
    include('session.php');
    
    $res  =  mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM member where mem_id=$loggedin_id");    
    $num_rows  =  mysqli_num_rows($res);

    if  (!$num_rows)  {
        header("location:  welcome.php?remarks=failed");
    }
    else
    {
    $titlu = $_POST['titlu'];
    $descriere = $_POST['descriere'];
    $joy = $_POST['joy'];
    $comm = $_POST['comm'];
    
mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE member 
               SET titlu = '$titlu',
               descriere = ' $descriere ',
               joy = '$joy',
               comm = '$comm'
               where mem_id=$loggedin_id");
    header("location:  welcome.php?remarks=success");
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use mysqli_insert_id get last id insert. Then update with id.

Comment: but what if someone else gets there first with another insert?